# Prevent Google Chrome from breaking double quote and open bracket to a new line?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have some text inside a paragraph tag, here's the snippet I'm having an issue with:

```
...a professional software company.  "[Manufacturers are] using software of different...
```

In Google Chrome browser, the following occurs:

```
...company. "
[Manufacturers are]...
```

but I would like it to behave how it does in other browsers, like so:

```
...company.
"[Manufacturers are]...
```

Is there a workaround for Chrome breaking the open bracket to a new line after a double quote? I'd like to keep the double quote and open bracket (plus the word "Manufacturers") all on the same line.

EDIT: jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/v1wf4bao/

Comment: Can you post your HTML code to better understand your problem?

Comment: Can you show a code snippet? or a jsfiddle? and what version of Chrome are you using and on what OS?

Comment: jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/v1wf4bao/